# Loopback - watch a change on a column

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

Let's say I have a model `Product` and there are two columns `Name` and `Quantity`.

I would like to update some other model whenever there is a change in `Quantity` column.

Is it possible to do this using `before save` or `after save` hook where I can get the difference (newInstance and instance in db)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be the appropriate way using the hooks.

Comment: That requires an additional DB call though. Also, please move this answer to comment.

Comment: "I would like to update some other model whenever there is a change in Quantity column". Will always have 2 db actions.

Comment: How will I get the difference in quantity? That ll need one DB call for current quantity in before save hook. I want to avoid that.